# How to make 3d Decals

Tags: rendering, image

I have created some geometry and want to make a 3d decals like the Decal Machine Addon. Is there anyway to make without addon a 3D decal.

[image]

I have created 1 decal but its flat not a 3d.

[image]

I want to create this type of 3d decal from the decal machine addon how to achieve without addon.

[3d Decal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMadU.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the result you're looking for, but if it is you can unwrap your object, projecting the UV-map from view (hotkey <kbd>U</kbd>). And then move and scale the UV-map over the normal texture (decal image.png).

[image]

Then when you apply the material to your object, it will look like this:

[image]

**Edit:**
(because comments do not allow for enough characters)

I thought you made a nice decal, and if you wanted it to be more 3D you could add it to your 3D model. I thought that was clear. Maybe a bit silly of me because i understand that often the point of using decals is to minimize the use of actual 3D geometry, So i did some digging.

It seems the Decal Machine Addon does not simply use normal maps. It adds to the illusion of geometry using **parralax mapping or parralax occlusion**. I don't know enough about it, but i believe that is currently not easy to do with Blender alone (hence, i suppose, the existence of the Decal Machine Addon)

Here are some resources on the subject (that also have .blend files implementing the technique):

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/parralax-occlusion-for-blender-2-8/3641 ,

https://blenderartists.org/t/parallax-shader-with-silhouette-clipping-for-blender-2-8-eevee-and-cycles/1162334

and

https://blenderartists.org/t/parallax-mapping-with-silhouette-clipping-shader-node/561285

They might be of more use to you than my answer

Comment: Can u plz make it clear little more and send the below file

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your question (in my defece, the video provided could have been better). I edited my answer a bit to hopefully put you (or anyone else) on the right track.