# Decal Machine Question

Tags: add-on

I saw a convenient Blender Add-On, and before purchasing I wanted to ask if anyone in the forum please confirm if you use Decal Machine, if I place an object in front of a decal, does it look like it's actually sitting within depth of the decal, like in the example I have uploaded. This is a reference photo I found on the internet and trying to see if it actually looks realistic within blender.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: In this video you can see parts of the decal image/texture hiding other parts of it, as actual geometry would (skip to 1:20) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KW9Pk9h6D8k Also here is an answer with some links at the end that might help anyone tying to achieve this parallax occlusion mapping effect without add-on: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185716/how-to-make-3d-decals/185725#185725 (I don't know about adding actual geometry to such a decal)

Comment: I gave it a try and made an answer : )

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a different example of Parallax Occlusion Mapping, (not from the add-on mentioned but from here:
https://blenderartists.org/t/parallax-shader-with-silhouette-clipping-for-blender-2-8-eevee-and-cycles/1162334 )

But as you can see, the visible part of the added geometry (white object) lies on top of the texture. The wall surface is flat and the POM only creates the illusion of extra geometry (like a normal map but more advanced). Therefore the wall can not interact with the white object as actual geometry would.

I strongly suspect the same would be true for the DECALmachine add-on.

Comment: The guy who developed Decal Machine, uploaded a quick video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRUxFizVALU&feature=emb_logo

So it works.

Comment: Ah, I guess it depends on the situation. The illusion isn't broken if you stay within certain borders of a particular decal. That looks very nice : )